# Prevent or encode ’ to '

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I had an issue. I do not want to insert `’` to the database.

Because when reading the `’` it will turn out with funny character.

Is there a way to prevent or encode `’` to `'` when inserting to MySQL?

Comment: Replace this character with js before saving.

Comment: can it be done using php?

Comment: @Danlee absolutely! Take a tour of php.net docs.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php  and it's example is in given link of  Michael_B   which is `$output = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $input);`

Comment: Can you set this as an answer so I can mark off?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace that specific string why not just doing:

```
$encoded = str_repace("’","'",$input);
```